Does Agasthyagama lizard mentioned in any scriptures?
When, i heard that there was lizard named, "Agasthyagama". I was surprised that this creature's name is in Sanskrit and make sense that this creature can be mentioned in any of our scriptures.
So, my question is, Does any of our scriptures mention about this "Agasthyagama" lizard?
